# arguments to pip should be passed from tox or poetry or shell?

Tags: python, pip, continuous-integration, tox, python-poetry

A project uses `tox` and `poetry` to manage the Python environment during continuous integration (CI) testing (install Python packages before running tests). The project root directory has files `/tox.ini` and `/pyproject.toml`.

In the CI workflow, a shell script `/runner.sh` calls `tox`. The `/tox.ini` instructs `tox` to call `poetry install`.  The `/pyproject.toml` has a few settings which `poetry` passes to `pip`.

**I want to pass some particular arguments to `pip`, e.g. `--disable-pip-version-check`.**

**What is the best way to pass arguments to `pip`?**
Should I edit `/tox.ini` or `/pyproject.toml`?  Is there a field in either file that will guarantee some particular arguments are passed to child invocations of `pip`?
Should I set an environment variable within the controlling shell script `/runner.sh`?

Comment: I thought newer versions of poetry didn't use _pip_. What poetry version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a complete answer, but when you decide to set the env in the shell script, please do not forget to set the [passenv](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) option, as `tox` "blocks" all environment variables to provide a clean state.

So, the questions boils down to how `poetry` passes information to `pip`, and that is something I cannot answer.

I think there is no difference whether you set an env variable in your shell script (and then set `passenv` in `tox`) or you set the environment directly in `tox` via `setenv`.

If I were you, I would just try it on my dev pc. The pleasure of `tox` is that you can run it both locally and in CI.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably set up some global options for pip, either via configuration file `pip.conf` or maybe via environment variables (not sure on this one): https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration